# Continuous functions carry compact sets into compact sets. Proof Attempt

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, compactness, open-map

I'm reading loomis and this is left as an exercise but I'm not convinced I'm right. Can you please verify my proof and help me finish it? Also, what is the difference between compact and sequentially compact? Because up to this point the book talks about sequentially compact not compact, but the question is copy pasted from the book, so I'm a bit confused about terminology. Anyway here's the proof:
$ \\ $

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$  be continuous, $f(X)=Y$, and abuse notation by putting a metric $d$ on both $X$ and $Y$. Also $X$ is compact. I try to prove $Y$ is compact by showing any sequence $\{y_n\}\in Y $ has a convergent subsequence $\{y_{i(n)}\}\rightarrow y\in Y. $ Since $f$ is continuous, $\forall \tau>0, \forall n, \exists B_{\tau}(y_n)$ for which $\exists U_{n}\subset X $ that is open that is the preimage of $B_{\tau}(y_n)$. We can now define a sequence $\{x_n\}\in X$ by defining $x_n$ to be some arbitrary element in $ U_n$. Because $X$ is sequentially compact, $\exists \{x_{i(n)}\}\rightarrow x\in X \implies \forall \epsilon>0, \exists i(N)=K:\forall i(n)=k \geq i(N)=K, d(x_{i(n)},x)<\epsilon, i.e. x_{i(n)}\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$. Note that in this part of the proof I struggled to prove for big epsilon, but it still works for small ones I think. Please help for this to work for all epsilon not just small ones. Anwyay, $U_n$ is open so $\exists B_r:x\in B_r\subset U_n$, $B_r$ open by definition of $U_n$ being an open set. Thus we can easily pick $\epsilon<r$ so that we obtain $x_{i(n)}\subset B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset B_r(x)\subset U$. Now we get $f(x_{i(n)})\in f(B_{\epsilon}(x)) \subset f(U)=B_{\tau}(y_{i(n)})$. In particular because $f(x)\in f(B_{\epsilon}(x))\subset B_{\tau}(y_{i(n)})$ we have $f(x)\in B_{\tau}(y_{i(n)})$ and by definition $d(f(x),y_{i(n)})<\tau$. We can do this for all $\tau>0$ so that we get that the subsequence $\{y_{i(n)}\}\rightarrow f(x)$. This completes the proof. In addition to feeling insecured about the whole thing, I used $\epsilon<r$ which feels wrong, as for epsilon big, what forces x to be inside of U? I know it probably has to because the earlier statement holds for all epsilon, but if epsilon is large I don't think there's a way to show this. As a result I don't see why $f(x)$ would be in the ball centered at $y_n$, so really my proof is for epsilon less than r, so some ball contained in U. Also, as if this post wasn't bad enough, I used some metric here, could someone help to show this strictly topologically? Is it as simple as just dropping all the epsilon stuff and replacing balls with open neighborhood? Thanks. I'm looking forward to a reply.

Comment: So $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces? By the way, you definitely need $f$ to be surjective.

Comment: Yes I should have specified it I think, the metric is d, and yes I think I see why you're saying that f takes all of X to all of Y.

Comment: Do you really need to go through all the $\epsilon$'s? I'm sure by this point in Loomis' text you can just invoke basic facts about continuity. Just take any sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $f(X)$. Then, $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$, and by (sequential) compactness of $X$, we have some subsequence $\{x_{n_i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ converges to some point $\xi$. Therefore... what does $f(x_{n_i})$ converge to? Why?

Comment: Also, the definition of compactness (every open cover has a finite subcover) is given a few pages later (page 214), where it is also proven that in a metric space, compactness (in the sense of open covers) is equivalent to sequential compactness, so it seems like you should just persevere and keep reading :)

Comment: Ah ok ty. But for your previous post, you construct a converging sequence in Y. But the problem is to show this for any sequence {y}, not any in {x} also converges in {y}

Comment: you should re-read my first comment carefully and understand why it shows $f(X)$ is sequentially-compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{y_n\}$ be an arbitrary sequence in $Y$. Then since $f$ is surjective, each $y_n$ is of the form $y_n=f(x_n)$. Now, $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence, say $\{x_{a_n}\}$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\{f(x_{a_n})=y_{a_n}\}$ must be convergent. but this is a subsequence of $\{y_n\}$, so you are done.

**P.S.** Surjectivity of $f$ is absolutely necessary. Consider $[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$.